# When it's OK to omit "where?"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When it's OK to omit "where?" For example, is it OK to omit it in the following sentence?

> This is the one of the few places (where) you can breathe real air.

In which situations one's not allowed to do this?

Comment: Everywhere where the meaning does not change, and there's no possible ambiguity, *where* & *that* can and are commonly dropped (elided).

Comment: Also _when_ (... the day [  ] the butterfly unfurls from the cocoon); _who_ / _whom_ (a woman [  ] I know).

Comment: @Kris Omitting *that* is nonstandard when the relative clause contains a gap in subject position.

Comment: Isn't that covered by Kris's '_where the meaning does not change_, and there's no possible ambiguity'? -'What's that noise I can Hear?'  – 'The new people that moved in next door.' v 'The new people moved in next door.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generally omit *where* when the head noun suggests a place:

> 1a. This is the one of the few **places** [ where you can breathe real air. ]
>    1b. This is the one of the few **places** [ you can breathe real air. ]

Here, the head noun is *place*, which of course suggests a place.  However:

> 2a. This is the **web page** [ where the claim was first made. ]
>    2b. *This is the **web page** [ the claim was first made. ]

Example 2b is ungrammatical because *web page* is unlikely to suggest a place.

(Examples 2a and 2b are taken from "A Student's Introduction to English Grammar" by Huddleston and Pullum, page 185.)

---

In this answer, * marks a sentence as ungrammatical in standard English.

Comment: I disagree; the restriction is far tighter. *This is one of the few beaches you can safely bathe. */??Blackpool is one location you will find plenty of places to eat.

Comment: I disagree; the restriction is far tighter. *This is one of the few beaches you can safely bathe. */??Blackpool is one location you will find plenty of places to eat. See also (the end of) Araucaria's (2016) answer at ['Isn't that the place which kids under 12 can't enter?' – is it correct ...?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297987/isnt-that-the-place-which-kids-under-12-cant-enter-is-it-correct-to-use/298061#298061).

Answer (score 0):

When the word *where* changes the meaning of the sentence you are not allowed to omit it.

For example:

*In the goldmine, where the dwarfs work, the air is unbearable.*

*where* refers to the goldmine. But when you remove it, the sentence is no longer correct.

*In the goldmine, the dwarfs work, the air is unbearable.

You would have to change it to:

*The dwarfs work in the goldmine. The air is unbearable.*

And that still doesn't completely mean what the first sentence means.

The second would be questions indicating location.

*Where is ...*

Comment: This is not an answer, because it assumes what the OP is asking: how do you know that "when you remove it, the sentence is no longer correct".

Comment: This answer applies to the OP's question, and it's basically the same as snailboat's answer, I just answered first and used wording that everyone understands. There is no reason for the downvote @Colin Fine

Comment: No it isn't the same. How is one to know whether or not _where_ changes the meaning of the sentence? Snailboat answered that question, you ignored it; but it is essentially what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a special feature of the noun *place.* For many other nouns that have similar meanings, it's not possible to omit *where.*

I posted an answer to another question that gives more details: [Relative pronouns "where" and "when": where can they be omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432219/relative-pronouns-where-and-when-where-can-they-be-omitted/432263#432263)