# Relative pronouns "where" and "when": where can they be omitted?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ellipses, relative-pronouns, when, where

I know the "omitting-rules" regarding the relative pronouns *who/which/that* and *whose.* How does it work with *where* and *when?* In the first sentence I cannot omit *where* but I can easily omit *when* in the second sentence. What is the rule?

1. I saw John in the shop where you bought your brown T-shirt.
2. I met Laura on the day (when) I missed the train to Barcelona.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That question only really covers subjects. The answer there only addresses subjects too, not objects, objects of preposition phrases, predicative complements and so forth.

Comment: @Araucaria The question there addresses 'He went back to Santa Monica which/where was his hometown.' This addresses 'The office will be moved to a place which/where is near my apartment.' Perhaps you could explain the difference (other than the fact that one is a defining clause).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, here the confusion can be reduced to not understanding, quite generally, when to use *where* or *which*.  There the question boils down to whether *where* can be a subject. Although they are related, they aren't the same. The more general question is the most useful for future readers. (In addition to which, the answer there is contentious - because it is not at all clear cut why *where* should be a subject in JL's fourth example. It can be analysed as a straightforward locative complement).

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer and quick fix:**

Look at the gap in the relative clause. If the gap can be filled in with the pronoun *it*, use the relative pronoun  *which*. If the gap can be filled in using the locative preposition *there*, use the relative word *where*:

- That's the restaurant which [I hate ____ ].
- That's the restaurant **which** [I hate <s>**it**</s>].
- That's the restaurant where [I met my wife ____ ].
- That's the restaurant **where** [I met my wife <s>**there**</s>].

Note that the strikethough across the words *it* and *there* indicate that we cannot actually leave these gaps filled!

---

**Full answer:**

This question is about relative clauses. These are special clauses with gaps in them. They modify other phrases, in particular noun phrases, which is the kind of case we are considering here.

The nominal or noun phrase which is being modified always occurs before the relative clause, and is referred to as the ᴀɴᴛᴇᴄᴇᴅᴇɴᴛ. So in *the dog, which they adopted*, the phrase *the dog* is the antecedent, and the phrase *which they adopted* is the ʀᴇʟᴀᴛɪᴠᴇ ᴄʟᴀᴜsᴇ modifying that noun phrase. Relative clauses are often introduced by *wh*-words such as *which, who* or *where*, or by the relative word *that*.

The word *which* is a pronoun and can be thought of as standing in for noun phrases. The word *where*—according to 21st Century grammars such as *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002) or *Oxford Modern English Grammar* (Aarts 2011)—is a locative preposition and can be thought of as standing in for preposition phrases (some people conjecture that *where* is a 'pro-preposition').

---

**The Question**

It is very confusing for students and teachers alike when considering why we use *which* or *where* when the antecedent of a relative clause can be thought of as a place:

- That's the restaurant where I met my wife.
- That's the restaurant which I hate.

I've heard teachers and linguists try to explain this in terms of phrases like *the restaurant* representing a place in the first example and a thing in the second. This is just silly.

The truth is that whether we use *which* or *where* in the sentences above doesn't depend on the status of the antecedent, *the restaurant*, either conceptually or in terms of its role within the larger sentence. Rather, it depends on the grammatical function that that phrase would occupy *in the relative clause itself*.

If we look at the sentences above , we can see that there is a gap in the clauses following the relative *wh*-word:

- That's the restaurant where [I met my wife <s>at the restaurant</s>]
- That's the restaurant which [I hate  <s>the restaurant</s>]

We can see that the relative word is co-indexed with that gap, so that we understand the relative word to refer to the missing portion of the clause:

- That's the restaurant where<sub>(i)</sub> [I met my wife ____ <sub>(i)</sub>]
- That's the restaurant which<sub>(i)</sub> [I hate ____ <sub>(i)</sub>]

Now, you'll notice that the gap in the relative clause in the first sentence can be replaced with a preposition phrase and the gap in the second sentence can be replaced by a noun phrase. As a rough rule of thumb, we can say that when the relative word is indexed with a gap fillable with a noun phrase, we use *which* (or *that*), and when it is indexed with a gap fillable with a preposition phrase, we use *where*. That is why the *it/there* test described in the short answer works. *It* is a pronoun which can work as a noun phrase. *There* is a locative preposition which can stand in for a larger preposition phrase.

However, it is probably more accurate to consider the grammatical relations that the gap has within the relative clause (rather than what type of phrase it could be replaced with) as being the crucial factor. So it's best to think in terms of whether the missing phrase is a Subject, Object, Predicative Complement or Object of a preposition—in which case we need to use *which*— or whether it is a Locative Adjunct, or the Locative Complement of a verb—in which case we need to use *where*.

To see why this might be a better description consider the following:

- She ate using her fingers, which I hate ___. (Object)
- She ate using her fingers, which ___ annoyed me. (Subject)
- She ate with her fingers, which everyone was horrified at ____. (Object of a preposition)

Here the word *which* can be thought of as representing a finite clause, instead of a phrase headed by a noun. Certainly in the first two sentences the gap in the relative clause could be replaced with one (if it was a stand-alone sentence):

- I hate [that she ate with her fingers].
- [That she ate with her fingers] annoyed me.

Of course, those gaps could also be plugged with a pronoun:

- I hate it.
- It annoyed me.

In the third example, the word *which* seems to be referring back to a clause, but the gap in the relative clause can only really be thought of as representing a noun phrase:

- Everyone was horrified at it.
- *Everyone was horrified at that she ate with her fingers.

Nonetheless, it is hard to show for sure that in the first two examples, the gap represents a pronoun or other noun phrase, rather than a clause. There are also instances where we might consider the relative relative word *which* and the gap it is indexed with to be representing an adjective phrase or verb phrase, for example. It may be simpler and more consistent, therefore, to refer to the grammatical function of the gap within the clause, rather than the type of phrase which is being deleted.

Here are some examples where the gap is functioning as a Locative Complement or Locative Adjunct:

- This is the drawer where [I put my pen ___ ]. (Locative Complement)
- That is the town where [I used to live ___ ]. (Locative Complement)
- That is the park where [Bertha plays football ___ ]. (Locative Adjunct)
- That is the pub where [I bet Bob £5 that Scotland would beat England in the rugby _____ ]. (Locative Adjunct)

Notice that a sense of location is not enough to make us want to use *where*. If we leave a normal preposition in place in the third example above, the gap will become the Object of a preposition, in which case we will need to use *which*, not *where* - even though the park obviously represents a location:

- That is the park which [Bertha plays football in ____ ].

---

<sup>**Grammar notes:**</sup>

<sup>Many traditional grammars regard *where* and *there* as adverbs instead of prepositions. This is fine and doesn't affect the story above very much - apart from that we lose the neat general correspondence of prepositions usually representing preposition phrases and pronouns usually representing noun phrases within relative clauses.</sup>

<sup>Adjuncts are embellishments that we stick onto well formed clauses to give extra information. They're often preposition phrases or adverbs. Complements, in contrast, fill a special slot set up by the verb. So *in the park* is an Adjunct in *She plays football in the park* but a Complement in *We put the statue in the park* (consider *we put the statue* where there seems to be some kind of missing information). Locative Adjuncts or Complements are merely ones that tell us about goals, sources or locations. They have their own special behaviours.</sup>

Comment: But isn't this sentence grammatical: "That's the restaurant where I met my wife at."? Assuming for the moment it is grammatical: why can we use "where" here, when the gap is fillable by an NP, not a PP?

Answer (score 5):

### You can omit the relative word only if it's possible to use "that" to introduce the relative clause

I think "I met Laura on the day I missed the train to Barcelona" should  actually be analyzed as a simplification of "I met Laura on the day **that** I missed the train to Barcelona" rather than of "I met Laura on the day **when** I missed the train to Barcelona".

In other words, I would say that there is no general rule of being able to omit *wh*-relative words like *when* and *where.* We can only omit the *th*-relative word *that* (and of course, there are some contexts where *that* cannot be omitted). I think the preceding statement is correct, but I'm not totally sure. Please let me know if you think of any exceptions (I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you refer to "omitting-rules" for *whose*). As Araucaria seems to say in the comments, my view here is probably not falsifiable, but I just find it a simpler way of thinking about things.

Note that you cannot say "*I saw John in the shop **that** you bought your brown T-shirt." And correspondingly, you cannot say "I saw John in the shop you bought your brown T-shirt" either. "I saw John in the shop **where** you bought your brown T-shirt", with "where", is perfectly correct, but I don't think it's particularly relevant.

### You can have a relative clause like this if the preceding noun can be used as the head of a "bare-NP adverb"

"['Missing Prepositions' and the Analysis of English Free Relative Clauses](https://semlab5.sbs.sunysb.edu/%7Erlarson/larson87mps.pdf)", by Richard K. Larson (1987), says "headed relative clauses containing a trace in adjunct position, but neither a relative adverb nor a stranded preposition, typically are well-formed only if their head belongs to the class of *bare-NP adverbs,* adverbs that can function adverbially without an accompanying preposition" (p. 239).

We can say "I missed the train to Barcelona that day", using the NP "that day"—without any preposition before it—as an adverbial adjunct, but we can't say "*You bought your brown T-shirt the shop" (we would have to use a preposition, like "You bought your brown T-shirt in the shop").

### List of nouns that can be the head of bare-NP adverbs

Larson has another article, "[Bare-NP adverbs](https://semlab5.sbs.sunysb.edu/%7Erlarson/larson85bnps.pdf)", where he describes some examples and categorizes them.

He says that there are very few bare-NP adverbs of location: the only ones he knows of are the words or phrases ending in *place,* as in "They have failed every place they have been tried" (as well as the pro-forms *there* and *where*) (pp. 596-597). So it should be possible to "omit where" if you rephrase your sentence to use the noun *place*: "I saw John in the place you bought your brown T-shirt."

Here are some examples from Google Books of "place" being used similarly:

- > Using a sharp utility knife (**the place you bought the Plexiglas** should have a knife designed for cutting acrylic), score the line to be cut several times.

  (*[Project Arcade: Build Your Own Arcade Machine](https://books.google.com/books?id=xD_cslWu4qkC&pg=PT460&dq=%22the%20place%20you%20bought%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY7JCWhrjZAhXm5YMKHZm4DHUQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20place%20you%20bought%22&f=false),* by John St. Clair)
- > You know that if you were to cover the pencil completely with the paper, the pencil would still be there, **in the place you left it,** were you to later search for it.

  ("Object perception and object knowledge in young infants: A view from studies of visual development", by Scott P. Johnson, in *[Perceptual Development: Visual, Auditory, and Speech Perception in Infancy](https://books.google.com/books?id=mlh2EfS2HIQC&pg=PA211&dq=%22in%20the%20place%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVkfGdh7jZAhWL14MKHexDCUA4MhDoAQhPMAc#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20place%20you%22&f=false),* edited by Alan Slater)

Of course, just because "place" can be used this way doesn't mean it would be the best choice for your particular sentence.

Bare-NP adverbs of time are more numerous; Larson mentions *moment, minute, hour, day, month* and *year,* and words or phrases ending in *time* (as well as the pro-form *then* and the deictics *now, yesterday, today, tomorrow*) (pp. 595-596).

Comment: The shop where they met was beautiful.  I saw them in the shop where they met.  Nothing wrong with 1).

Comment: @Lambie: 1) is fine as it is, but Ines wanted to know why we cannot say "I saw John in the shop you bought your brown T-shirt" (without "where") to express the same idea.

Comment: I don't think changing the word shop to place solves it.  I think you need where and it isn't a relation pronoun. The OP is confusing relative pronouns and subordinate clauses.

Comment: @Lambie: I can't see how "where" is a conjunction in sentence 1). A relative clause is a kind of subordinate clause introduced by a relative word and attached to a preceding noun phrase that serves as the antecedent for some understood element of the relative clause. In the sentence "I saw John in the shop where you bought your brown T-shirt", the clause "you brought your brown T-shirt" is understood to mean "you brought your brown T-shirt [in that shop]". It is introduced by the relative word "where" and follows the noun phrase "the shop" which serves as the antecedent.

Comment: [["omit where" if you rephrase your sentence to use the noun place: "I saw John in the place you bought your brown T-shirt." ]] For me, that does not work. All you did is replace shop with place. I think the "where" is needed, regardless of what you call it.

Comment: @Lambie: I edited my question after your last comment to add some examples that seem parallel to me. What do you think of them? I don't particularly like the sound of "I saw John in the place you bought your brown T-shirt," but I don't really feel that it is ungrammatical. It just seems awkward to me.

Comment: Not sure you can avoid it.  I saw John in the shop at/in which [i.e. where] you bought your shirt.

Comment: @Lambie: I agree that that sentence is grammatical. Because you said you find "I saw John in the place you bought your brown T-shirt" ungrammatical, I'm wondering what you think of "the place you bought the Plexiglas should have a knife designed for cutting acrylic" and "the pencil would still be there, in the place you left it, were you to later search for it." Does either of these sound acceptable to you?

Comment: Why do you say "*I think "I met Laura on the day I missed the train to Barcelona" should actually be analyzed as a simplification of "I met Laura on the day that I missed the train to Barcelona" rather than of "I met Laura on the day when I missed the train to Barcelona*" ? Is there any syntactic reason for saying so?

Comment: @Araucaria: it just seems simpler to me, since there are other contexts where “that” and the zero relativizer are interchangeable.

Comment: @sumelic But there are other contexts where other relative words are omissible. Just about any where *that* is omissible could equally be analysed as contexts where a different relative word is missing ...

Answer (score 1):

I saw John in the shop |where you bought your brown T-shirt|.

**where you bought etc**. is **a subordinate clause with where as a conjunction. Same as when, see below for the reference**.

[where as a conjunction, Oxford Dictionary](http://Where%20as%20a%20conjunction%20We%20use%20where%20as%20a%20conjunction%20meaning%20%E2%80%98in%20the%20place%20that%E2%80%99%20or%20%E2%80%98in%20situations%20that%E2%80%99.%20The%20clause%20with%20where%20is%20a%20subordinate%20clause%20and%20needs%20a%20main%20clause%20to%20complete%20its%20meaning.%20If%20the%20where%20clause%20comes%20before%20the%20main%20clause,%20we%20use%20a%20comma:)

I met Laura on the day |when I missed the train to Barcelona|.

**when I missed the train to Barcelona** is a subordinate clause with when as a conjunction.

[when clause, Oxford Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/when)

Neither where or when is **a relative pronoun** in those sentences.

I met Laura on the day **that** I missed the train to Barcelona.
I met Laura on the day I missed the train to Barcelona.

**That is  a relative pronoun and can be omitted because it is the object of the clause**.
[omitting that](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml)

Comment: In what way is "that" an object of the clause "[that] I missed the train to Barcelona"?

Comment: Well, I was thinking that meet on a day is like a direct object. Maybe it should be called something else. What would you call it?

Comment: Well, I would say "a day..." is the object of the preposition "on" in sentence 2), but the role of the noun phrase in the matrix clause is unrelated to the role of the parts of the relative clause. For example, if we said "I met Laura on a day that hadn't been going well for me", then even though "a day..." is the object of the preposition "on", the word *that* cannot be omitted. Same for something like "I will always remember the day that came after"; it can't be replaced with "I will always remember the day came after" just because "the day..." is the object of the matrix clause.

Comment: Ok, let me say it differently. There are two clauses, a main  (matrix) clause and a subordinate, linked by that.  Therefore, the that is not needed.  The clause is not embedded or anything like that.

Comment: I do see embedded clauses in both sentences. Here is how I bracket them (using [] for clauses and {} for noun phrases): [I saw John in {the shop where [you bought your brown T-shirt]}] and [I met Laura on {the day (that) [I missed the train to Barcelona]}]. Something like "I met Laura on the day, when I missed the train to Barcelona" using *when* as a "conjunction" doesn't make sense to me in this sentence (and if *when* were being used as a conjunction, I would expect the sentence to be punctuated with a comma like that).

Comment: (Actually, I'm not sure if the relative pronouns should also be considered part of the clause, but I don't think it makes much difference: [I saw John in {the shop [where you bought your brown T-shirt]}].)

Comment: Where as a conjunction
We use where as a conjunction meaning ‘in the place that’ or ‘in situations that’. The clause with where is a subordinate clause and needs a main clause to complete its meaning. If the where clause comes before the main clause, we use a comma: Oxford Dictionary And when can also be used as a conjunction, see my links in my answer.

Comment: I can see how these words are considered to be conjunctions in some contexts, but I don't think that is the correct analysis in these particular sentences.

Comment: Why do you think you can omit *that* but not *where*?

Answer (score -1):

When a relative pronoun is the subject of the following sentence, we use a verb after it.
For example: The man who lives next door *is* very friendly.

But when a relative pronoun is an object, we use a subject and verb after it.
For example: The man whom *I wanted* to see was not there.

Pay attention to the difference between them. You see, when a relative pronoun is subject, it should not be omitted but when it is an object you are allowed to omit it.

The rule I mentioned is for all relative pronouns.

Reference: English grammar in Use

Comment: There are several things wrong with this. (1) It isn’t true, unless by “after it” you mean “at some point later in the sentence”; (2) You’ve italicised the wrong verb in your first example, which makes the explanation almost nonsensical; (3) It doesn’t answer the question—_when_ and _where_ are neither subject nor object in the sentences in the question.

Comment: Please read my post again and you will find your answer..in the 2 sentences above which Ines presented we see subject and verb after relative pronoun so in both cases relative pronoun can be omitted because they have the role of object..besides sir if the rule I mentioned has problem then we conclude one the best books in English grammar has problem.because,I have read this rule in book.I don't say sth off the top of my head

Comment: No. There is a subject and verb after the relativiser in both examples, but that does not mean the relativiser is the object in the clause. Both clauses have objects: “your brown T-shirt” and “the train to Barcelona” are the objects. The relativisers are **not** objects in those sentences. Relativisers do not need to be either subjects or objects; they can have other functions as well, as indeed they do here. In fact, only _who(m)_, _which_ and _that_ can function as subject and object at all; other relativisers cannot.

Comment: so Would you please tell me what are the role of when and where in the sentences above?

Comment: Subject always come before verb so if a relative pronoun which is before verb does not have the role of subject ,then what can it be?

Comment: No, subjects do not always come before the verb—only when there is no inversion in the clause. And other constituents can come before the verb as well. I would say that _when_ and _where_ generally function as what traditional grammar would call ‘adverbial constituents’, more specifically, they are pronominal stand-ins for prepositional phrases (_where_ might even be argued to be a fused-head prepositional phrase itself).

Comment: How do you claim that "when" is a pronominal stand-in for prepositional phrase? It does not make sense for me....when is a part of prepositional phrase I agree,but how do you argue that "when "can be deleted because it is a part of prepositional phrase?

Comment: I don’t claim that. _When_ is never part of a PP; it is (sometimes) a stand-in for one. It can be the relative equivalent of ‘in an hour’, for instance, but it cannot be the equivalent of ‘an hour’ alone (‘in when’ would be ungrammatical). It can also, as mentioned in sumelic’s answer, be the equivalent of a bare-NP adverbial, which carries out the same adverbial syntactic function as the PP (‘he did it Saturday’ = ‘he did it on Saturday’); in this usage, it is omissible. When it is equivalent to a time adverbial that cannot be expressed as a bare NP, _when_ cannot be omitted.