# I've found <somewhere/some place/a place> where

Tags: relative-clauses, antecedents

> a. I’ve found **somewhere where** they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.
>
> (From [this Guardian news article](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/jul/05/its-all-gloom-and-despair-in-the-uk-but-as-an-outsider-i-still-think-its-wonderful))

Is it just me or is the repetition of *where* bothering anyone else? Why not just lose the second *where* as in (b)?

> b. I’ve found **somewhere** they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.

Alternatively, how about using 'some place' or 'a place' (I find the one word 'someplace' a bit too colloquial)?

> c. I’ve found **some place where** they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.
>
> d. I’ve found **a place where** they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.

Does (b), (c) or (d) sound any better than (a)?

---

[None of the answers to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/432219/118290) addresses my question directly or competently.

Firstly, omitting *where* is not the issue here. The issue is what the alternatives to *somewhere where* are. Only (b) brings out the issue of omitting *where*.

Secondly, the earlier question cannot even resolve the issue of omitting *where* as in (b). The only answer there that discusses omitting *where* is @herisson's:

> ...the words or phrases ending in *place*, as in "They have failed every place they have been tried" (as well as the pro-forms *there* and *where*)

Which means that *where* can be omitted when the antecedent ends in *place*, *there* or *where*. But this is not readily applicable to *somewhere* because it's not clear whether a compound word like *somewhere* should be considered an antecedent ending in *where* in @herisson's answer. Moreover, @Michael Harvey and @Hot Licks disagree as to the acceptability of (b).

Last but not least, regardless of whether (b) is an acceptable alternative to (a) or not, I'd like to also know whether (c) and (d) are acceptable alternatives, which is decidedly the more important issue of the question. And neither (c) nor (d) involves the issue of whether to omit *where* or is covered by the earlier question in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: I find 'someplace' a bit too American, as well as colloquial, but that is opinion-based, like this question.

Comment: The writer is saying that London is where people apologise if you bump them 'on a crowded tube'. Although British people all over the country do that, only London has an underground railway system often informally called 'the tube' (small or large T). People often use "a tube" (small or large T) to mean a train on that system. So it's London. Whether you consider London a 'place' is a matter of opinion and context. If the double 'where' bothers you (I don't mind it), I would support your (b) and (d) suggestions, but not (c).

Comment: B isn't right -- it has a different meaning.

Comment: Hot Licks - I perceive 'take me somewhere where I can buy a beer' and 'take me somewhere I can buy a beer' to mean the same.

Comment: ... But 'Take me a place I can buy a beer' sounds distinctly non-standard, slang. The dropping of the relativiser 'where', while not always eschewed, seems a work in progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative pronouns "where" and "when": where can they be omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432219/relative-pronouns-where-and-when-where-can-they-be-omitted)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - " I’ve found somewhere they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube."  I was searching the Interweb and found somewhere an article that says they will apologize to you if you bump them with a backpack on a crowded tube.  (Though why you'd perch a backpack on a crowded tube I don't know.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please see the addendum.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Please tell me what part of my question is "opinion-based". Note that _someplace_ is not included as an alternative to consider.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you mean _Take me **to** a place I can buy a beer_?

Comment: No; I'm dropping 'where' from the already non-standard, but not unknown¶ [[Katie Wilson](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lO1mDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=%22take+me+a+place%22&source=bl&ots=alMu1YpYSa&sig=ACfU3U0SL0r0RK75eB1aiDQyK8xohD8SZg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22take%20me%20a%20place%22&f=false)], ''Take me a place where I can buy a beer' (¶eg 'take me a place where the summers are long'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't that a poem? Why would you bring up lyrics, which could hide behind poetic license, in a comment to a grammar question?

Comment: It's a slang usage. I've heard it in gangster movies. The dropping of 'where' is not uncommon, but is of arguable acceptability in varied instances.

Comment: This is like repeating the last 2 letters of the first word in this sentence as the second word. It's a matter of style and personal preference, not something that 'needs' fixing for the sentence to be understood.

Comment: @Lawrence If (a) doesn't need fixing, then just think of (b)-(d) not as fixes but as alternatives.

Comment: B  can be interpreted as “I found somewhere that they apologize...”    Like I was reading somewhere (I can’t remember where) that ...

Comment: You can't expect a qualified answer to a question which is posed in a very confused way.

Comment: @Nico It's hard to understand what you mean the question "is posed in a very confused way". It's even harder to understand what you mean by 'a qualified answer'.

Answer (score 1):

Specimens ***a***, ***c***, and ***d*** are correct. Specimen ***d*** is the most natural. If you omit *where* (as in specimen ***b***), [*somewhere*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/somewhere) ceases to function as a noun (meaning *some unspecified place*) and instead functions as an adverb (meaning *in some place*). That changes the meaning. So though you could say that ***b*** is correct, ***b*** is not a more euphonious version of ***a***.

Here (***a***), *somewhere* functions as a noun, modified by a relative (adjective) clause headed by the [relative adverb](https://www.thoughtco.com/relative-adverb-1692041) *where*:

> *I’ve found **somewhere** where they apologise to you if you bump them.*
>
> *I’ve found **some unspecified place** where they apologise to you if you bump them.*

Here (***b***), *somewhere* functions as an adverb (kind of like *somehow*), modifying the verb *found* and followed by a *that-clause* (which functions as a noun):

> *I’ve found **somewhere** [that] they apologise to you if you bump them.*
>
> *I’ve found **in some place** [e.g. in a book or on a website] that they apologise to you if you bump them.*
>
> *I’ve found [that] they apologise to you if you bump them.* (adverb/adverb phrase can be omitted)
>
> Not:
>
> **I’ve found some unspecified place [that] they apologise to you if you bump them.* (incorrect; a noun phrase doesn't work here)

Here (***c*** and ***d***), *some place* and *a place* function as nouns, each modified by a relative (adjective) clause headed by the relative adverb *where*. 
In the context of your sentences, *some* is an informal version of the indefinite *a*:

> *I’ve found some place where they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.*
>
> *I’ve found a place where they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.*

Answer (score -1):

**(d) and (c) are correct**: “some place” in (c) and “a place” in (d) are antecedents; both are followed by restrictive where-clauses.

See: [Cambridge dictionary grammar on “where”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/where), section *Where* as a relative pronoun.

In [the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529830/ive-found-somewhere-some-place-a-place-where/530360#comment1293313_529830), Michael Harvey argues that “some place” sounds a bit too American. I can relate. I prefer (d) to (c).

**(b) is also correct**, but its meaning is slightly different. It is not (c) with “place” omitted. Rather, it is

> I’ve *discovered* *that* somewhere they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube.

with “discovered” replaced by its synonym “found (out)”, and with “(the fact) that” omitted.

The object phrase needs not start with “somewhere” since “somewhere” is not a relative, but an indefinite pronoun:

> I’ve found (that) they apologise to you if you bump them with your backpack on a crowded tube, somewhere.

I agree with you that **(a) sounds the least correct**: the double “where” sounds somewhat off to my ears.

Comment: Thanks. But I think the antecedent is 'place' in (c) and (d). And please note what @MichaelHarvey finds "a bit too American" is not 'some place' but 'someplace', and I have told him that the latter is not even presented as an alternative.

Comment: There might be grammars out there that consider only the main noun of a noun phrase to be the antecedent, but to me it makes more sense that the entire noun phrase (so including “some” or “a”) is the antecedent, since the relative phrase modifies/restricts the entire noun phrase.

Comment: Since I’m unable to hear the space in “some place” when pronounced without any distinguishable pause in between, “some place” and “someplace” sound alike, and both sound American. ;-)