# Is "where" the only relative pronoun that cannot be omitted from an adjective clause?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, pronouns, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

When using adjective clauses, the relative pronoun can be omitted when it is not the subject of the sentence. For example:

"She is the person I ran into."

In the above example, being the object of the sentence, the relative pronoun "who" (or whom) was left out.

BUT

This is true as long as the relative pronoun is not "where". In case of "where", even if it's not the subject of the sentence, it cannot be omitted from the sentence. It can only be replaced with "that" or "which", and that requires a preposition at the end of the sentence. For example:

"This is the building we met." is wrong, but

"This is the building where we met." is correct, as is "This is the building that/which we met in."

You don't have to do this with other relative pronouns. They can be left out from the sentence without a problem, as in "I'm thinking about the time we met." The pronoun "Where" is the only one that cannot be omitted from the clause altogether.

I just need to know if I'm right about this. Thank you.

Comment: Relative clauses are not adjectives; they are either modifiers in NP structure or supplements. "Where" is best classified as a preposition, where it functions in the relative clause as an adjunct of place. A 'that' or 'bare' relative is possible as "I know a place (that) you can relax."

Comment: @BillJ Ah, but that’s due to exceptional properties of the noun *place*! You couldn’t do that with the noun *restaurant*!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. But it does prove that it is not _always_ obligatory.

Comment: @Askeladd "Why" and "when" can also be omitted in a "that" or 'bare' relative, as in "I know the reason (that) she go so angry" / "I remember the day (that) you were born."

Comment: @BillJ Thanks. Yes I know, but I'm asking about the one that CANNOT be omitted, and apparently "where" is the only one that cannot be removed. It has to be replaced, not omitted. That's not the case with others. They can be both replaced and removed altogether.

Comment: @Askeladd I gave you an example in my first comment. It can be omitted where the antecedent is a very general noun, such as "place", for example "This is much better than the place we stayed last year."

Comment: @BillJ What other very general nouns can we use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-pronoun *Wh*-relative words have idiosyncratic restrictions, and enter into many idiosyncratic constructions. *Where* is a good example; so is *why*.

> Both *where* and *why* are less common than *that* in relative clauses relating location or purpose, but I'm going to ignore *that* here; it's a separate issue, and only arguably a relative pronoun in any case.

*Where* can be deleted from its relative clause (without substituting *that*), but only in a relative clause whose antecedent is the word *place*. Similarly, *why* can be deleted only when its antecedent is the word *reason*. Other words, even words denoting places or reasons, just don't work with these *Wh*-relative words.

- *That's the place (where/that) we met/lived*.
- **That's the location/house/city/apartment/block we met/lived*
- *That's the reason (why/that) they came/argued.*
- **That's the purpose/cause they came/argued*

This is either the result of or the cause of the non-constituent fixed phrases *place where* and *reason why*. Other similar phrases don't seem to be tidelocked into one particular noun, though.

- *That's the time (when/that) we quit/he wants to leave.*
- *That's the hour/day we quit/he wants to leave.*

Of course, these restrictions pale beyond the restriction on *how* -- it can't be used as a relative pronoun at all, no matter what its antecedent is. Either *that* or zero is used instead.

- **He doesn't know the way how he should salute*
- *He doesn't know the way that he should salute.*
- *He doesn't know the way he should salute.*

Like *what* -- which also can't be used as a relative pronoun -- *how* **can** be used to mark a headless relative, where *what* equals 'that which' and *how* equals 'the way which'.

- *He doesn't know what he should do.*
- *He doesn't know how he should salute.*

These are also common with relative infinitives, which include modal senses like *should*.

- *He doesn't know what to do.*
- *He doesn't know how to salute.*

But relative infinitives are way too complicated to discuss here, thank gods.

Comment: I prefer to call "what he should do" and "how he should salute" nominal clauses (functioning, of course, as objects of the verb "know"). To me that seems simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing *relative pronouns* and *relative adverbs* here.

*Who*/*Whom*, *That/Which* are indeed relative pronouns, but *Where* is a relative adverb.

I believe the confusion stems from the fact that both relative pronouns and relative adverbs refer back to an antecedent. While that's true, that's not the whole story.

Relative pronouns and Relative adverbs function differently in a sentence: the former as *objects* and the latter as *adjuncts.*

Comment: "When" is also a relative adverb, yet it can be omitted from the sentence. The word "when" in "I'm thinking about the time we met." is also not the object.

Comment: "Where" is best classified as a preposition (in/at/from some place).

Comment: @Askeladd It seems to me that the word omitted in *"I'm thinking about the time we met."* is "that". In the examples given, "where" is adverbial/an adjunct as it comprises a preposition + NP = at/in/by, etc, the place/which, and the preposition is vital to the semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can think of "She is the person I ran into" as involving omission of the relative pronoun *who(m),* I think the clearest way to describe relative clauses with no explicit relative words is by comparing them to relative clauses starting with *that.*  If there is no corresponding *that* relative clause, you won't be able to leave out a relative word:

- No *"This is the building that we met" (it is syntactically possible, but doesn't make sense), so also no *"This is the building we met."

In general, *that* can be omitted from a relative clause that contains a subject:

- "She is the person that I ran into" > "She is the person I ran into"

*That* clauses are most often interchangeable with clauses containing the relative pronouns *which* or *who(m)*. However, *that* can also be interchangeable with the relative words *where* or *when* in relative clauses coming after certain special types of noun phrases:

- "I remember **the day** *when* I moved in to my apartment"

   "I remember **the day** *that* I moved in to my apartment"

  "I remember **the day** I moved in to my apartment" (could be seen as "omission of *when*")

A noun phrase headed by the noun *place* can marginally, for some speakers, allow a *that* relative clause or a clause without an explicit relative word:

- "This is the place where we met"

  ?"This is the place that we met"

  ?"This is the place we met"

See my answer here for more details and references: [Relative pronouns “where” and “when”: where can they be omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432263/77227)

Both *where* and *when* are often not categorized as pro**nouns** when they are used to form relative clauses. Their categorization is argued (as you can see, Araucaria's answer to the linked question says that *where* is a locative preposition or "pro-preposition"; traditional grammar calls it an "adverb" in this context.)

Comment: I would certainly classify "where" as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ and that's why it cannot be removed, right?

Comment: No, not right! Consider this example: "This is much better than the place we stayed last year."  Note the absence of "where". But as I said in my previous comments, a bare relative only works with very general nouns, like "place".